# What is the super-bunching effects of composite boson?

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate, bosons

What is the super-bunching effects of composite boson ?

Comment: you can just google that and read the papers on it

Comment: I did not found good article to understand phenomena,

Comment: can you give a link for "super" in the bunching effect? for example I have found "non-local" bunching here https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.01168 . Could it be related to *super*conductivity and *super*fluidity?

Comment: It is related to the composite bosons made up of pair bosons. When coboson starts to condens if constituent bosons do not have enough entanglement ,constituent bosons starts to show there bosonic nature too